# Finding the process for the shell script

Tags: shell

Suppose if one executes

while [ true ]; do echo "hello"; done; on the shell directly.

How do I find the process for the same and kill it afterwards?

Comment: You cannot kill just the while loop: it is not a separate process, it is running in the shell. You can kill the shell, but finding that shell that is running that while loop may be tricky. I used to put `$$` in my prompt so I could know the pid of the shell to kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends a bit how hacky you want to be, and how much you're willing to break.

If you run this in Bash, for example, and try to look for the process in for example `ps wafux`, **there is not going to be any subprocess** started by any of those commands since they are all built-ins (see `man bash` for details). The only way to kill that from outside the same shell is to kill the shell itself, with for example `killall bash`. That's not very nice, but should at least accomplish the result in "normal" cases on some *nixes.

If it's the last **background** process you started in the shell you can kill it **in the same shell** using `kill $!`. If you haven't started any other `bash` processes since starting it you can run `pkill --newest bash` from other shells.

[Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) is a great relevant article which highlights some incredibly ugly hacks which are far too common and dangerous. The whole site is well worth a read.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer for your question but would have been too cumbersome to express in a comment.

The way I use to detect these never ending scripts I end up creating a symlink of bash using

```
ln -s /bin/bash ~/bin/mybash
```

and then use run your scripts using `~/bin/mybash`. Something like:

```
~/bin/mybash -c 'while [ true ]; do echo "hello"; done;'
```

Then you can search process list by `mybash` instead of `bash`.